# Default value on form select (with foreach loop)

Tags: forms, laravel, select, foreach, default-value

So, I want to achieve a `<select>` like solution where a default value is equal to the value that is currently in the database, so the 'old value'.

## 1

I have this, where I loop a foreach to fill `<option>`.:

> ```
> <select id="size"  name="size" class="form-control">
>     @foreach ($sizes as $s)
>         <option value="{{ $s->value }}">{{ $s->name }}</option>
>     @endforeach
> </select>
> ```

Now where I want to use this is an **edit-form** in laravel 5.2 where it fills in this form with the current values from the database for the selected user. My input fields with text fill in correctly but this select doesn't.

## 2

Working with Laravel forms I know this is possible to set the default value to **S**. But I don't know how to loop this is foreach...:

> ```
> {{ Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S') }}
> ```

So I need to find a way to set default value with HTML-select tags while in a loop with values from my controller **or** find a way to loop in Laravel Forms.. Either is good, as long as it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is what You are asking, but if You know current value, You can check it with if statement:

```
<select id="size"  name="size" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($sizes as $s)
        @if ($s->value == $currentSize)
            <option selected value="{{ $s->value }}">{{ $s->name }}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{ $s->value }}">{{ $s->name }}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: This adds quit some bulk.. Works for now, but isn't there something like `Input::old()` for select options?

Comment: `Input::old()` returns flash data, so You can use `@if (Input::old('size') == $s->value)` if old input is presented to view layer.

Comment: Yes, this cleans it up nicely. Thanks